# Как сделать парсер

Tags: парсер

В общем, есть тг канал, куда приходит два раза в день сообщение и в нём есть ваучер и мне нужно что бы парсер копировал этот ваучер и вставлял его в браузере и нажимал кнопку активировать.
Прошу рассказать из каких этапов будет состоять этот парсер и возможно ли его вообще сделать?

Comment: сделать возможно все. ответ зависит от ваших навыков. никто не знает их уровень и, к примеру, я могу это реализовать на Java, где есть огромное количество инструментов по работе с телеграм : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram вопрос : сможете ли это сделать вы?

Answer (score 1):

1. этап - обработчик сообщений в тг,откуда вы сможете брать ваучер(iogram)
2. этап - чтобы активировать ваучр вам нужно отправить post или get запрос ,вам нужно исследоваь что это за запрос,куда его отправлять и какие параметры нужны(инструмент разработчика в баузере)
3. этап отправить этот запрос!

Да,это конечно возможно,делов на пару часиков! (Обычный request)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, только вот если вам не сложно можете пожалуйста написать для какого этапа какая библиотека нужна? Благодарю